# Pandas adding double quotes on column names

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple data frame:

```
   CategoryID CategoryName
0           1    Category1
1           2    Category2
```

read from a csv file, which I dump into a postgres 11 database with this code:

```
df.to_sql("productcategory", mySqlalchemyEngine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

but the table is created with double quotes around the column names:

```
CREATE TABLE public.productcategory
(
    "CategoryID" bigint,
    "CategoryName" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

so a `select CategoryID from...` wont work. I have to do `select "CategoryID" from...` which I dont want to.

how can I prevent those quotes from being added?

Thanks

Comment: Use lowercase letters when naming tables/columns/etc, then it won't matter if there are quotes or not.

Comment: hey, that actually works, thanks, but why did the columns were created with double quotes in the first example? I mean, the double quotes were part of the column name as "select CategoryID from..." didnt work.

Comment: Postgres identifiers by default are always lowercase. That is, if you do `CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID, Col1)` postgres will create a table called `mytable` with columns `id, col1`, and `SELECT ID FROM MyTable` becomes `SELECT id FROM mytable`. I guess the python libs add quotes to the identifiers, maybe because they contain uppercase, I don't know. But when you add quotes (`CREATE TABLE "MyTable" ("ID", ...)`), postgres will create them with the exact casing used in the creation statement. [cont...]

Comment: Then when you want to access them, you have to use quotes as well, because `SELECT * FROM MyTable` looks for a table called `mytable`, but the table name is `MyTable`. So you would need to do `SELECT * FROM "MyTable"` to select from a table with that exact name. That's why getting rid of uppercase works: if the names in postgres are all lowercase, you can do `SELECT ID FROM MyTable` if you want in your client, as the identifiers in your select statement will be converted to lowercase in postgres.